# Possible to extract a full data dependency tree using e.g. Jailer?

Tags: sql, db2, data-extraction

I need to populate our IBM DB2 performance test database. I would like to take one row and all its dependencies from one of our test relational databases, and then copy/paste the row(s) in a script.

Is is possible to use e.g. Jailer to extract one row from the DB and all its dependencies? I.e. it would extract all the rows that are in this row's FK, but also those rows to which this row's PK is a FK in some other row. I have been looking at Jailer, but I can only mange to extract rows of one table, not all its dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is possible, by removing the associated dependencies "disable" option which seemed to be checked by default.